# Value of JSON object is an array [Typescript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, csv

I have a set of data filled with an excel file. I want to pour the data into my database that I exported the file as csv and parsed it to a JSON object.

```
fname,lname,phone
Terry,Doe,[123456789]
Jane,Doe,[123456788, 123456787]
```

By parsing the csv into JSON object, with no surprise, I get the array quoted in the convertedData.

```
[
 {
   "fname": "Terry",
   "lname": "Doe",
   "phone": "[123456789]",
 },
 {
   "fname": "Jane",
   "lname": "Doe",
   "phone": "[123456788", 123456787]"
 }
]
```

What I actually want is a JavaScript object that I can manipulate it like normal array, say:

```
convertedData[0].phone[0]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Hope this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/wvabBZE helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you won't be able to do `data[0].phone`, you can do something like `data[0]["phone"]`.

```js
//You can replace this part with your CSV parsing - I put it this way so you could run and test it.
const rawData = "fname,lname,phone\nTerry,Doe,[123456789]\nJane,Doe,[123456788, 123456787]";
const lines = rawData.split("\n");

const data = [];
const keys = [];
lines[0].split(",").forEach((key) => keys.push(key));
for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const line = lines[i];
    const parsedLine = {}
    line.split(",").forEach((value, index) => parsedLine[keys[index]] = value);
    data.push(parsedLine);
}

//print a test case
console.log(data[0]["phone"])
```

Comment: data[0]["phone"] returns a string: "[123456789]". What I wish is a real array, like [123456789].

Comment: You can technically run `eval(data[0]["phone"])` but keep in mind this is *very risky* and should only be used on trusted data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval